# Distributed database app in Golang getting OOM killed

Tags: go, memory-leaks, out-of-memory, oom

I am creating a distributed database application in Golang. The application is running inside a K8 pod with a memory limit of 10GB. I am tracking the Max RSS size of the process and Go Heap Memory stats within a separate go routine. As I increase the load the process gets killed by OOM. Before OOM happens, I see Max RSS hits the 10 GB, but Go Heap Memory goes up and down but never goes beyond 8GB. Questions.

1. How do I determine that if there a memory leak?
2. The account of permanent data structures (like map, global data structures, etc) usage shouldnt not go beyond 2 GB according to calculations. Where is all the memory going?
3. How can I avoid OOM kills for my process?

Comment: OOM Kill happens by Linux kernel. So, I think you can find a way to check the process's memory in Linux. And To check the memory leak, you can investigate your code at first, or utilize go mem profiling. Depending on your situation, you can use `GOMEMLIMIT` for avoiding excessive memory usage of your process.

Comment: Or it can be helpful to limit your load at DB such as rate limiter.

Comment: Before you decide to use `GOMEMLIMIT`, please read this document https://tip.golang.org/doc/gc-guide because there is a tradeoff between the performance and its limiting memory.

Comment: I printed RSS value of my process and Go readmemstats.Alloc every minute and it seems like when both increase linearly with load, but in steady state both values hover around some number. However, RSS value is almost 3x the Go Alloc value. What does that mean?